# Endpoint with Google Flex env

Tags: wcf, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

There is bit of a confusion, wondering if somebody can help me with this.

Here is an example which is a year old and uses goapp with polymer and endpoint
https://github.com/googlesamples/cloud-polymer-go

Here is a recent example using gcloud 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine_flexible/endpoints

Both are different as google changed its approach.

As per second example, I am able to create endpoint functions which uses json for input and output. However there are 2 problems

1st. It is throwing error if I put functions in different file under same package. It works when I run go run *.go. but then I dont understand how app.yaml come into picture. I think this url /_ah/spi/.* should work

2nd. I am using postman app to check the request and response from endpoint. Is there a better way? I thought google does provide a platform to test endpoint.

Is there any example which implements examples similar to 1st one with new libraries?

looking forward for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Testing endpoints is done via the url `https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://yourprojectid.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/` Or if you are testing on localhost, you can replace base with `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/`.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear - This is not working for me. Do I need to make some changes in app.yaml?

Comment: In addition to what polymer/backend has, I have this handler before the spi one. `- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  secure: always` It's the same but url is `/.*`

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that this url is easier to use for deployed instances. `https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`. This link is to python docs, but is the same across the board as far as testing endpoints https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/endpoints/test_deploy

Comment: @RayfenWindspear First of all thanks for your help. it showing nothing .. api explorer sidebar on left but on right hand side .. no apis

Comment: If you are testing on localhost, you have to use firefox and disable the protections. In firefox, you'll get a lock with a red cross through it in the top left of the navbar, click that and disable protections. Then it will connect to localhost.